# What's the formal definition of limits where both the variable and the function tend to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I've seen the definitions for limits like $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ and limits like $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$. Both are based on the use of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ because you're getting arbitrarily close to a real number $L$ in the first case and a real number $c$ in the second case.

But what about limits like $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$? For example, $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^x = \infty$

I'm guessing we can't use the same definitions as before because unlike $L$ and $c$, $\infty$ is not a real number. So how do we define it withous using $\infty$ as a number?

This is my attempt:

The expression $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ means that for all $M>0$, there exists an $N>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ for all $x > N$.

I've tested my definition for $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^x$ and it seems to work fine. But I'm suspicious that my definition is not rigorous enough or that there's something wrong with the part where I say that $M>0$ and that $N>0$. If my definition isn't correct, could you also give me an example of a limit where it would fail?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't even need the $> 0$ part.

Comment: Yes your definition is perfectly fine

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @Trebor , and Andrew